# how to import spring xml outside of a jar

Tags: xml, spring, configuration

I have a spring xml importing another spring xml. Now I want to make it more flexible by putting the second xml outside of the jar.

I am wondering to do do this??

```
 <import resource="pipeline.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to specify path to a resource in Spring, depending on your requirements you can either prefix the path with `classpath:` (and specify a location on the classpath) or `file:` (filesystem resource). More explanation [in the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/resources.html#resources-resource-strings).

Comment: Thanks it works. BTW, how do I make it optional, which means ignore it if not found, instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: You could use a wildcard, for example: `<import resource="file:/path/to/conf/*.xml">`. It should still work if there were no path matches found.

Comment: @kryger what if there are 2+ .xml in the path will the wildcard work

Comment: @kryger, how to mention relative path for filesystem resource ? do we always have to mention the absolute path ?